# Testing Spring Batch 5 job

Tags: spring-batch, junit5

I am trying to test a Springbatch 5.0 job but I have still not figured out why I am getting this issue. I have looked at several documentations and suggestions on how to fix it but it has not helped me. So bringing it here for help.

> ERROR o.s.b.c..AbstractStep [main] Exception while closing step
> execution resources in step someStep in job
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name
> 'step' at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java.java)
> ~{spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4] at
> org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSoiurce.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java)
> ~{spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4] at
> org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader$$SpringCGLIB$$0.open()
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]

```
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(Config.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobUtils;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("filename", "testname").toJobParameters;
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED,jobExecution.getStatus());

}
```

}

```
public class StepConfigClass {
//Autowired others

    public Step step(@Qualifier("writer") FlatFileItemWriter writer, @Qualifier("reader") FlatFileItemReader reader) {
        return new StepBuilder("testStep",jobRepository)
            .<obj,obj1>chunk(100,transactionManager)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
    }
}


@StepScope
@Configuration
public class ReaderWriter {
    @value("#{jobParameters['filename']}")
    private String fileName;

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<obj1> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<obj1> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        ...other configs
    }

   @StepScope
   @Bean
   public FlatFileItemWriter<obj2> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<obj2> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setFooterCallback(t -> t.write(fileName));
        ...other configs
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@StepScope` on the `StepConfigClass` adds no value, it should be removed.

If you want to test step-scoped components, you need to make sure to have the `StepScopeTestExecutionListener` added on your test, see: [Testing Step-Scoped Components](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-step-scoped-components). This should already be the case if you use `@SpringBatchTest`.

EDIT: based on question edit and comment:

After your edit, there is `@StepScope` on class `ReaderWriter` which is incorrect as well. You need to remove that too and move the injection of `fileName` where is it needed, meaning in the item writer bean definition:

```
@Configuration
public class ReaderWriter {

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<obj1> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<obj1> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        ...other configs
    }

   @StepScope
   @Bean
   public FlatFileItemWriter<obj2> writer(@value("#{jobParameters['filename']}") String fileName) {
        FlatFileItemWriter<obj2> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setFooterCallback(t -> t.write(fileName));
        ...other configs
   }

}
```

Comment: I updated the class name just to separate the reader, writer class from the stepconfig class. I am trying to run the job and not a step as standalone. When the job gets to that particular step, it throws that scope error message

Comment: After your edit, there is @StepScope on class ReaderWriter which is incorrect as well. You need to remove that too and move the injection of fileName to where is it needed. I add an example in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me narrow down the issue. Removing the StepScope helped me see the actual error message Springbatch was throwing.